# Dynamic theme switching on routes that have no layout handle

Tags: layout, event-observer

## The problem

When implementing a dynamic theme switcher using `controller_action_layout_load_before` it turns out that certain routes do not have layout handles. This is due to how they load layout; in that technically they don't.

Consider **checkout/onepage/progress**:

```
public function progressAction()
{
    // previous step should never be null. We always start with billing and go forward
    $prevStep = $this->getRequest()->getParam('prevStep', false);

    if ($this->_expireAjax() || !$prevStep) {
        return null;
    }

    $layout = $this->getLayout();
    $update = $layout->getUpdate();
    /* Load the block belonging to the current step*/
    $update->load('checkout_onepage_progress_' . $prevStep);
    $layout->generateXml();
    $layout->generateBlocks();
    $output = $layout->getOutput();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($output);
    return $output;
}
```

It generates XML and Blocks, but never actually calls `loadLayout` or `renderlayout`.

Because of this we cannot use layout handles to affect change. This is not ideal.

## The question

Because of this, when affecting a theme change for Onepage checkout I'm forced to parse the requested Route. I don't like this:

```
public function controllerActionLayoutLoadBefore()
{
    $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();

    if($request->getModuleName()=='checkout' && $request->getControllerName()=='onepage'){
        //do the theme switching
    }
}
```

Is there a better way? I've considered at least issuing `loadLayout` from a rewrite of OnepageController, but that requires a rewrite and I don't like that.

Comment: It seems the problem is further complicated - many ajax routes load blocks which should have theme-dependent templates. This likely means that a store switch is required. Any thoughts on how to avoid that?

Comment: Can you not listen to `controller_action_predispatch`? Pretty sure the area is loaded just before the event which should load the design package singleton, so presumably you could change the package / theme at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the `predispatch` event. It always gets fired and has the route info that you need.

Use this in your `config.xml`

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_progress>
            <observers>
                <magento_test>
                    <class>magento_test/observer</class>
                    <method>changeTheme</method>
                </magento_test>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_progress>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Then in the observer you could have-

```
public function changeTheme($observer) {
    Mage::getDesign()->setPackageName('hello')->setTheme('world');
}
```

Comment: This is how I worked it out myself. However, it doesn't work with Enterprise Full Page Cache as predispatch isn't fired on cached routes. The search continues!